# SQL LINQ to Datatable Doesnt Refresh When DataSourse Change

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, dataset, datasource

Following Is the Code To Populate GridLookUpEdit(Dev Express) or any combo from LINQ. 
The Problems Is That when Underlying Datasource Changes It doesnt Refresh

```
    Dim l_LNQUserAccess = (From TBU_User In PB_DT_User
                            Join TBU_AccessLevel In PB_DT_AccessLevel
                            On TBU_User.Field(Of Guid)("AccessLevelDID") Equals TBU_AccessLevel.Field(Of Guid)("PKGUID")
                            Where (TBU_User.Field(Of Integer)("BranchID") = Pb_ST_BranchInf.LoginBranchId) And (TBU_User.Field(Of Integer)("Operation") <> PB_EN_DBOpp.Delete)
    Select New With
        {
            .PKGUID = TBU_User.Field(Of Guid)("PKGUID"),
            .UserID = TBU_User.Field(Of String)("UserID"),
            .Descr = TBU_User.Field(Of String)("Descr"),
            .AccessLevelID = TBU_AccessLevel.Field(Of String)("AccessLevelID")
        })

    Dim bs = New BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = l_LNQUserAccess


    l_GLE.Properties.ValueMember = "PKGUID"
    l_GLE.Properties.DisplayMember = "UserID"
    l_GLE.Properties.DataSource = ""
    l_GLE.Properties.DataSource = bs
```

Comment: Are you calling `ResetBindings()` when the `DataSource` changes?

Comment: no havent used it in any where in whole project

Comment: i am using import rows to import rows in datatables

Comment: ok just checked ResetBindings() but the problem is that changing datasource from another form so cant us resetbindings source